# Problems with threading in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to using threads in C++.

As a simple example, I need to write a program that creates a thread asking a number from the user, once incrementing and displaying it in the hand.

This is my solution:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void *thread_1(void *arg) {
    int i=0;
    printf("We are in the thread\n");
    printf("Put a number \n");
    cin>>i;
    i++;
    cout<<"i== "<<i<<endl;
    (void)arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1;
    printf("Before creating the thread\n");
    if(pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread_1,NULL)==-1) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pthread_join(thread1, NULL)) {
       perror("pthread_join");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
    printf("After creating the thread\n");
    return 1;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following result:

```
Before creating the thread
We are in the thread
Put a number
```

When I enter the number, the program froze. What is the problem? I remark that the problem is probably in the `cin>>` expression. When I delete this, my code works fine.

Comment: `(void)arg;` this is my favourite part

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing C-style `printf` calls with C++ `std::cout`?

Comment: @Salgar Maybe you're not very familiar with c. That line is completely valid in both syntax and logic.

Comment: Code works for me, maybe you have a buggy pthread implementation. Also there is no reason to kill the thread, just call return instead.

Comment: describe your enviorement: OS, IDE and version, Compiler

Comment: @bruno.karklis, I am working on OSX.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, we can mixt printf and std::out without problem. Just you have to include the libraries.

Comment: @phdstudent what is your IDE and compiller? the extension of your file is `.c` or `.cpp`?

Comment: @bruno.karklis, I am using QT and .cpp extension and the compilers gcc

Comment: @phdstudent if you want something to be compiled in c, just use `.c`, but, if you use `.cpp` your compiler will use C++ rules, by the way you can compile c code on C++ file, but... if you are working in something that need to be in C just use `.c` and never `.cpp`

Comment: @phdstudent please, refactory your code in C style...

Comment: @bruno.karklis, tahnks for your support. I changed my code as c++  and  after in C but it does not work. I do not think that is a compling probem. I think that it is a OS problem or like this.

Comment: @phdstudent, you might want to run your code inside a debugger like gdb. When your program hangs, you interrupt it (if inside gdb, Ctrl+C) to see where it is stopped, or if it is really stopped at all.

Comment: FWIW, the error checking is incorrect.  `pthread_*foo*()` functions return an error code (zero on success), which you code can then pass to `strerror_r()` (or assign to `errno` before calling `perror()`).

Comment: @pilcrow, sorry but I did not understand what you are saying.

Comment: @phdstudent, `pthread_create()` [does not set errno](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/pthreads-errors-and-errno/), nor does `pthread_join()`.  You want something like:  `if ((rc = pthread_join(...)) != 0) { errno = rc; perror("pthread_join"); }`.

Comment: @pilcrow  It does not work. The problem is with the cin>> function

Comment: @phdstudent Yes you can mix, but only as long as long as [the C++ streams and the C stdio is synched](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), which was not the case in earlier standard libraries. It's also generally considered bad style to mix like that, use one or the other (and of course I would recommend to use the C++ streams exclusively).